# Htaccess for multiple website codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i have a website with subdomain.

I trying to searching i google but still not worked with my projects.

my structure folder is :

```
-public_html
--subdomain_folder (this is codeigniter)
---htaccess_for_subdomain
--domain_folder (this is my own projects website)
---htaccess_for_domain
--htaccess_for_root
```

below is my htaccess code :

**htaccess_for_root (public_html)**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.go.id$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/^(.*)/files/source/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf|JPG)$ files/source/$2.$3 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain_folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain_folder/$1

# Change yourdomain.com to be your primary domain again.
# Change 'subfolder' to be the folder you will use for your primary domain
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.go.id$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ domain_folder/index.php [L]
```

****this is my htaccess_for_domain****

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/files/source/(.*)\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|swf|JPG)$ files/source/$2.$3 [QSA]

RewriteBase /web/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /domain_folder/index.php [L]
```

This is htaccess_for_subdomain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

When i access my subdomain (www.sub.domain.go.id) it always not redirecting properly.

and what i want is, when i access www.domain.go.id it will redirect to domain_folder and when i access www.sub.domain.go.id, it will redirect to subdomain_folder

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you is to use virtual hosts and set the documentRoot for each domain/subdomain to point to its specific folder.

Eg. (apache - I suppose you use apache as a web server)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin administrator@localhost
    ServerName  www.sub.domain.go.id
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/project/public_html/subdomain_folder
    <Directory /path/to/your/project/public_html/subdomain_folder/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.sub
            RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Do the same thing for your domain to point to the domain_folder.
You can find more details about virtual host for apache in this link
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/